# Lumen (Laravel) Eloquent php artisan make:model not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, lumen

I use Lumen 1.0 for an API project.

I have already enable Eloquent by uncomment the following line in **bootstrap/app.php** file :

```
$app->withEloquent();
```

But when I want to create my first model with migration it fails :

```
php artisan make:model Book --migration
```

Error message :

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "make:model" is not defined.
  Did you mean one of these?
      make:seeder
      make:migration
```

Laravel doc about Eloquent (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models).

Lumen doc (http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation) doesn't include Eloquent doc because, it's not enable by default.

Do you have any ideas to avoid this error ?

### Add details

```
php artisan --version
```

Displays :

```
Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.1.6) (Laravel Components 5.1.*)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're seeing this error because Lumen doesn't come with `make:model`.

To see a list of all the artisan commands you have at your disposal just run `php artisan`.

That being said I did just find this package which I've added to a lumen installation and it seems to work fine https://github.com/webNeat/lumen-generators#installation

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 37):

If you check all the available commands using `php artisan list` you will see that you don't have all the default ones offered by `laravel`. But you can get the most importants using the `lumen-generator` package (not to be confused with `lumen-generators`). It has the advantage of offering more commands than the other one mentioned.

To use it just install it using `composer`:

```sh
composer require flipbox/lumen-generator
```

Then enable it in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```php
$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
```

You will now be able to use all these new commands using `artisan`:

```sh
key:generate      Set the application key

make:command      Create a new Artisan command
make:controller   Create a new controller class
make:event        Create a new event class
make:job          Create a new job class
make:listener     Create a new event listener class
make:mail         Create a new email class
make:middleware   Create a new middleware class
make:migration    Create a new migration file
make:model        Create a new Eloquent model class
make:policy       Create a new policy class
make:provider     Create a new service provider class
make:seeder       Create a new seeder class
make:test         Create a new test class
```

Just have a look at the official documentation: https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator

Answer (score 14):

1. Go to the project directory and add the generators package to your `composer.json` using the following command:

   ```
   composer require wn/lumen-generators
   ```
2. Add following code segment to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

   ```
   public function register()
   {
       if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
           $this->app->register('Wn\Generators\CommandsServiceProvider');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that you have un-commented the following line in `bootstrap/app.php` to allow service providers on your project:

   ```
   $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
   ```
4. Run `php artisan list` on the project directory (document root). Now you will see new items there.

Answer (score 2):

just create your model file manually in the app directory

example

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {
    protected $table = ‘articles’;

    protected $fillable = [
        ‘title’,
        ‘description’,
        ‘body’
    ];
}
```

Comment: Should it be `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`  in lumen? or `Illuminate\Database..`

Answer (score 0):

$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class); add this line into "bootstrap\app.php" and save this file then make the command.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

there are some packages that can help you to have all of artisan command that you has on Laravel .
install below package to have more artisan command.
https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator

Comment: Please make more obvious the additional contribution this provides beyond existing answers, e.g. the much older and already upvoted one by johannchopin