# Artisan: Make Model not found

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-artisan

Right now I'm following a tutorial, where it led me to install Laravel Artisan extension in VS Code. It went to the point where I need to open a command palette and write `Artisan Make: Model` to create a model.

After I tried that, it shows an error message along with `command 'artisan.make.model' not found`

So umm, anybody know why this happen? Or any other way I can bypass this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try solutions on this page   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339517/lumen-laravel-eloquent-php-artisan-makemodel-not-defined

Comment: make sure you are in the project root directory and you must give space like this ``php artisan make:model ModelName``

Comment: also you don't have to use vscode plugin for running laravel artisan commands just open command prompt or terminal by ``ctrl+` `` then a terminal will pop up and there you have to run ``php artisan make:model``.

Comment: I already tried to install it. But then an error shown along with 
```Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires wn/lumen-generators ^1.3 -> satisfiable by wn/lumen-generators[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.4].
    - wn/lumen-generators[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.4] require illuminate/console ^5.1 -> found illuminate/console[v5.1.1, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.```

Comment: can you tell what are you installing laravel/lumen or laravel/laravel

Comment: there is already a solution for your composer error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441281/laravel-lumen-illuminate-console-wont-update

Answer (score 0):

For using Laravel Artisan extension:

Install  the `Laravel Artisan Extension (Author: Ryan Naddy)`

Make Sure you're in project work directory.

Then, Open command palette by shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+p`

There Search `Artisan: Make Model` and Follow instructions like next prompt will ask you for model name where you have to provide Name of your model and whether you want a controller/migration or not.

Same can be done by `Php artisan make:model ModelName -mc` just by opening command prompt or terminal so whichever way it suits you.

Note: I've tested this on ubuntu so let me know if you want more help.